# Speed up database query with function

Tags: php, mysql, performance, function

Hello my database query very slow. 5 minutes for listing 4000 rows in html table... Please help.

```
         **$query = "SELECT * FROM tblRazduzeniUgovori WHERE Status='razduzen'";**
         if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
             {
               echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='brojUgovora[]' value='" . $row['Broj'] . "'/></td>";
```

Thanks you.

Comment: Consider providing a SHOW CREATE statement for the relevant table and an EXPLAIN for the query

Comment: Is it the query that's slow, or generating and displaying the 4,000 rows in HTML that's slow?

Comment: Generating and displaying the 4000 row in HTML is slow

Comment: a good start would be to edit 'SELECT *' to more specific query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: add status as an index on the database table, this will speed up the select portion of the script.

Second: concatenate the string, rather than issuing an echo statement each time, echo * 4000 can be quite slow.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblRazduzeniUgovori WHERE Status='razduzen'";
     $output = '';
     if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
         {
           $output .= "<tr>";
           $output .= "<td><input type='checkbox' name='brojUgovora[]' value='" . $row['Broj'] . "'/></td>";
         }
      }
      echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

this might not be what you're looking for, but i suggest not to show so many rows, you can limit :)

```
<?php
$displayed_items = 100; // items displayed per page
$start = isset($_REQUEST['start']) ? $_REQUEST['start'] : 0;
$end = $start + $displayed_items;
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblRazduzeniUgovori 
          WHERE Status='razduzen' LIMIT {$start}, {$end}";
?>
<table>
<?php
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
           <tr>
           <?php foreach ($a as $row):?>
               <td>
                  <?php echo $a ?>
               </td>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
           </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
<form action='#' method='get'>
     <input type='hidden' name='start' value='<?php echo $start + $displayed_items ?>' />
     <input type='submit' value='next page' />
</form>
```

like that you can see results just bu **clicking next**, dont forget to add ORDER BY to the query